# Connecting Project Professional 2013 with Project Server 2013

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-server-2013

I am trying to connect my Microsoft Project Professional 2013 with Microsoft Project Server 2013 but following error keeps popping up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't tell you why exactly you are getting that error, but I can give you some tips on troubleshooting:

1. Make sure you can connect and do have permissions to the PWA site. From that same machine, can you browse to it in the web browser and view/create projects?
2. Assuming #1 looks good, you can use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the web requests that Project client is making to the server. Look at the responses coming back from the web server - does it yield any clues (error codes perhaps) as to what is wrong?

Maybe you can edit your question to add whatever information you find?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your URL is correct (including http vs. https) the issue is most like related to permissions.

The solution will depend on your security configurations for the Project Server environment.  If your Project Server 2013 environment is in Project Permission Mode, then the Global permissions for at least one your role(s) must have the following global permission selected:

**Log on to Project Server from Project Professional**

*"Allows a user to load the Enterprise Global Template when he or she connects Project Professional to Project Server. Grant this permission to all users in your organization who will be using Project Professional to connect to Project Server."*

If your Project Server Permissions are in SharePoint mode, the user must be a member of one of these groups:

- Administrators
- Portfolio Managers
- Project Managers
- Resource Managers

Permissions model references:
Project Server Mode: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197631.aspx
SharePoint Mode: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219510.aspx